# Refernces, pointer and variables in Java

Tags: java, pointers, reference, arguments

I usually program in python and C, so this world of java confuses me quite a bit.

I am looking for a way to make my code more elegant, and in these other languages I would do it by passing by reference (or with pointers, depending on the language), the variable.

At one point in the code, I repeat a piece of code several times because each one depends on a certain previous situation. In summary, it could be understood that I want to modify several variables with the same code block, for which I first want to select the variable that I want to modify, assign it a "nickname", and then work with the nickname but modify the original variable.

So i want to change this

```
if (condition){
    if (condition){
        //modify var1
    } else {
        //modify var2
    }
}else if (condition){
    if (condition){
        //modify var1
    } else {
        //modify var2
    }
}
```

for something like this

```
if (condition){
    nickname = var1;
} else {
    nickname = var2;
}

if (condition){
    // modify nickname
}else if (condition){
    // modify nickname
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Java? Or am I condemned (using this aproach) to have redundant code?

In *C* i could do something like

```
// nickname as pointer from type of var1 and var2
if (condition){
    nickname = &var1;
} else {
    nickname = &var2;
}

// Work over nickname
```

Comment: Could you show an equivalent of this in C or Python? I don't understand what you want from the description. Or some pseudocode is also fine.

Comment: This is how you would do it in Java. It's fine.

Comment: You cannot pass references like in C. But in this case, you can extract the code to a method, `return` var1 or var2 and assign the method's return value to `nickname`.

Comment: @ublec When i do this the value of var don't change

Comment: @f1sh I get that, butI would prefer that when altering to "nickname", the variable to which it had been linked had already been changed

Comment: @bench did you declare var1 and var2?

Comment: @ublec The question was general. But in the case in which I was urged I was working with String and first I declared them and then use the constructor of this class.

Comment: You should check out [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and also consider `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
if (condition){
    nickname = var1;
} else {
    nickname = var2;
}
```

This works ONLY if `var1` and `var2` are:

1. References to object instances (i.e. not primitive values)
2. Mutable, i.e. have internal state that can be changed (`String` is immutable)
3. Type-compatible with each other.  `nickname` must be assignable from both `var1` and `var2`

In that case you can use `nickname` to modify the internal state of a referenced object.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately this ends my search. I am working with `String`.

Comment: @bench The strings are **immutable** in `java`. So no matter how many references you have, you won't be able to modify them.

Comment: @bench Is your question actually answered at this point? I worry that you might think: "Changing a bunch of characters in Java is impossible.".

Comment: This probably won't fix it, you're right @akuzminykh.

Is there any way to do something like this but with `Strings`. In my code I am concatenating them, so i know that i can modify theme, but I create several variables that store things that will behave in a similar way, that is why I am looking for this behavior but for `Strings`.